# In Android SDK, how to run a for loop with many coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that renders an SVG on a view and produces a thumbnail (bitmap) for me. This has to happen at the beginning of the app, so all the SVGs and the thumbnails are loaded properly. Each cycle of rendering a new SVG takes a while. So, right now, this is my current solution (admittedly a very bad one). Because it takes a little white for the render to happen, I am pausing for 50 milliseconds between each two:

```
// this is the render function ~ Not important in this question
fun render () {
    drawView.invalidate() // refresh the view
    drawView.artwork = artworks[index] // find next artwork
    artworks[index].renderThumbnail() // render
}
```

// this is the current main function

```
fun main () {
        thread(start = true) {
            (0 until AppData.artworks.count()).map {
                render() // render a new SVG
                Thread.sleep(50) // because it takes a while, sleep for 50 millies
            }
        }
}
```

So, now I am trying to achieve the same with coroutines. Here is my coroutine approach that doesn't really work:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    (0 until AppData.artworks.count()).map {
        async(Dispatchers.IO) { 
            render() // render a new SVG
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciatd.

Comment: 2 questions: 'because it takes a while, sleep for 50 millies', what's it? Your  coroutine approach doesn't 'really' works. What works, what doesn't work?

Comment: Q1: The process of rendering the thumbnail. It takes a little while. I don't know how long, but by experimenting, I found that 50 milliseconds is enough. 
Q2: The coroutine passses through everything and none of the thumbnails get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your whole code so I assume you launch coroutines in the `main` method. So to wait all the coroutines to finish you should use `runBlocking` builder:

```
fun main () = runBlocking {
    for (i in 0 until AppData.artworks.count()) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // launch a new coroutine for each SVG
            render() // render a new SVG
        }
    }
}
```